# Locked icon for disabled accordions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I have disabled specific accordions and want to change the icons for them to ui-icon-locked.

I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();

     $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons",
        { 'header': 'ui-icon-circle-plus', 'headerSelected': 'ui-icon-circle-minus' });
        $( ".disabled" ).addClass("ui-state-disabled");
});
```

and:

```
 <h6 class="disabled">Bacteriology in practice: interactive modules</h6>
      <div>
        <p class="text"> Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
          Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
          ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
          lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
```

I have tried in the css:

```
.ui-accordion-header.disabled .ui-icon {
    ui-icon-locked;
}
```

But that doesn't work.

Also this doesn't work:

```
   $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();

     $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons",
        { 'header': 'ui-icon-circle-plus', 'headerSelected': 'ui-icon-circle-minus' });
        $( ".disabled" ).addClass("ui-state-disabled");

 $(".disabled").accordion("option", "icons",
        { 'header': 'ui-icon-locked', 'headerSelected': 'ui-icon-locked' });
        $( ".disabled" ).addClass("ui-state-disabled");
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just copy the css from `.ui-icon-locked` into the ruleset for `.ui-accordion-header.disabled .ui-icon`

Comment: wow...how simple was that.  I didn't think that the css for .ui-icon-locked would replace the icon with just background-position: -192px -96px;

Comment: I made my comment into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the css from `.ui-icon-locked` into the ruleset for `.ui-accordion-header.disabled .ui-icon`.

jQuery UI CSS uses sprite sheets, so you just have to change the `background-position` to get the new icon into view.